# How to display chinese characters in output file of a concurrent program in oracle apps

Tags: oracle

I'm working for Taiwan operating unit where supplier name is store in traditinal chinese language. I have written a package in which I'm displaying these chinese supplier name in fnd output file of a concurrent program. But in output file I see `?` (question mark) instead of chinese characters.

So can anyone tell me how can i output chinese characters?

Regards,
Pradvin

Answer (score 0):

Change profile Option at user level as below
Profile Option Name : FND: NATIVE CLIENT ENCODING
Value : ZHS16GBK

Regards,
Ashish Vishwakarma